# How can I let the Geometry Node particle disappear when reach the top?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

[image]Hi, I am new to geometry node here.
I have follow one of the tutorial on making bubbles effect with geometry node, but the bubble will return to its original mesh position when reach the max limit.

Here is the link for the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSwEuHend2I&t=2067s

How can I do for the bubbles to disappear when they reach the top instead of moving back to the mesh position. Thank you very much!

Comment: If u provide your blend file - I will try to help u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by passing a *Selection* to the `Instance on Points` node that checks the Z-position for a certain value.

Just enter in the node `Compare` the value that corresponds to this desired Z-position.

[image]